# SQL referential integerity recursively

Tags: mysql, referential-integrity

DDL for creating database is like this

```
create table manager
    (employee_name varchar(20) not null,
    manager_name varchar(20) not null,
    primary key (employee_name),
    foreign key (manager_name) references manager on delete cascade);
```

If instance of manager relation is like this

```
employee_name | manager_name
-----------------------------
A             | B  
-----------------------------
B             | C  
-----------------------------
C             | B  
-----------------------------
D             | B
```

In this case if I delete tuple (A, B) in this relation other tuple isn't deleted. I thought like that.

However book's answer is that all tuple is deleted. I can't understand why all tuple is deleted.

Comment: add employee_name to foreign key constraint:  foreign key (manager_name) references manager(employee_name) on delete cascade

Comment: That DDL was in book. Question was if one tuple in that relation is deleted, what happens

Comment: Your code is invalid. For a foreign key, you need to specify which column it refers to, it currently only specifies which table it refers to. If it refers to the primary key, you are right, it will not delete every row. But you should tripple check that what you are trying to do is what the book is telling you to do. Maybe there is another foreign key, a different foreign key, different sample data or you are supposed to delete a different tuple than `(A,B)` to get that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have **A, B, C and D as employees**. Among them you have defined **B and C as Managers**. And you have chosen to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` that means if you delete one parent tuple in table Manager, it will automatically affect the child one (table Employees).

Basically, if you decide to delete **both managers (B and C)** - **B had A, C and D as employees and C had B as employee**).

In that case, all tuples might be deleted on cascade as you defined on table creation.